# Number of candidates allowed in the final election.

Tags: discussion, election

10 candidates are allowed to participate in the election phase to choose moderators in this election. Is there any reason for the number 10? I've been reading the answers to the questions serious candidates take the time to answer thoughtfully(Moderator Election Q&A), and I dislike the idea of scrutinizing all the information there is to consider for 10 separate candidates to elect 3 moderators.

How are the number of candidates for the election phase determined?

Thank you.

Comment: Feature request to reduce it to 8: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102239/primaries-should-select-the-top-8-candidates

Comment: I think 10 down to 3 is fine. Perhaps 9 would have been neater, but think of it like a baker's dozen. 1 more, just in case. I think $3n+1$ is a nice formula for this. 3 people chasing each position. Of course, just reading 4 questionnaires would be easier, but not very fair...

Comment: @user1729 It's always 10, regardless of how many moderator positions are available: 2, 3, or 4.

Comment: @Behaviour Sorry, I should have said that I realised that, I was just saying that 3n+1 is nice. If there were 10 positions, we should have 31 candidates, not 10...and so on.

Comment: Many are called, but few are chosen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of candidates in the final round does not depend on the number of positions available. It is either $10$ or the number of contenders, whichever is less. If there are $10$ or fewer nominees, all of them go directly into the final round.

For details of the procedure, see [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360/)

Comment: Technically, this is the answer to my question. Thanks.